# Finding a particular value from a ng-repeating row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to find an ID or name of a certain row that is generated from a repeat. In this instance I am trying to post the particular rows invoice_no. Unfortunately I am not sure what I am doing in this case.

```
controller("myControllerMgmtVOM", ["myFactory", "$animate", "$timeout", "$q", "$http", "$filter",
    function(myFactory, $animate, $timeout, $q, $http, $filter) {
        var vm = this;
        var setLoading = function(loading) {
            vm.isLoading = loading;
        };
        vm.count = function(idx) {
            console.log(idx);
        };
        setLoading(true);
        $http.get("/index.php/Collections/getOpenAccountingAction/").then(function(res) {
            vm.vom = [];
            angular.forEach(res.data, function(val, idx) {
                vm.vom.push({
                    invcase_id: val.invcase_id,
                    invoice_no: val.invoice_no,
                    obj_id: val.obj_id,
                    contact: val.contact,
                    customer: val.cname,
                    open_date: val.fcdate,
                    followup_name: val.followup_name,
                    followup_date: val.fdatetime,
                    company_name: val.company_name,
                    notes: []
                });
            });
        }).then(function() {
            angular.forEach(vm.vom, function(val, idx) {
                $http.get("../Collections/getNote/?id=" + val.invcase_id).then(function(res) {
                    val.notes = [];
                    angular.forEach(res.data, function(note, idx) {
                        val.notes.push({
                            detail: note.note_text,
                            date: note.createddate
                        });
                    });
                    var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
                    val.notes = orderBy(val.notes, '-date');
                });
                $http.get('/arinvoice/getamount?invoiceNo=' + val.invoice_no).then(function(response) {
                    vm.vom[idx].amount_due = '$ ' + response.data.Amount_Due;
                    vm.vom[idx].due_date = response.data.Due_Date;
                });
            });
            setLoading(false);
        });

        vm.hideRow = function(rowID) {
        //var rowID = vm.vom.invoice_no;
        $http.post("/index.php/Collections/closeAction/?id=" + rowID).then(function(res){
            window.location = "/index.php/Collections";
        }); 
    };
    }
]);
```

Below is the front end:

```
<div class="marginBottom inline-flex">
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary pad-10" href="" data-ng-click="clickSearch='1'">Search</md-button>
</div>
<div layout layout-sm="row" class="search-container pad-10 vanish" data-ng-show="clickSearch=='1'">
    <md-input-container flex>
        <md-button class="md-primary md-raised pos-abs-right" data-ng-click="search=''">Clear</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-primary md-raised pos-abs-right" data-ng-click="clickSearch=''">Close</md-button>
        <label for="search">Keyword Search</label>
        <input name="search" id="search" type="text" data-ng-model="search" />
    </md-input-container>
</div>
<div layout='row' class="stripeRow">
    <div flex class="pad-10 stripeTeal">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'open_date'; reverse=!reverse">Open Date</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'invoice_no'; reverse=!reverse">Invoice Number</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10 stripeTeal">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'invcase_id'; reverse=!reverse">Invoice Case ID</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'amount_due'; reverse=!reverse">Amount Due</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10 stripeTeal">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'due_date'; reverse=!reverse">Due Date</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'customer'; reverse=!reverse">Customer/Company</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10 stripeTeal">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'contact'; reverse=!reverse">Customer Contact</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'followup_name'; reverse=!reverse">Assigned To</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10 stripeTeal">
        <strong><a href="" data-ng-click="prop = 'followup_date'; reverse=!reverse">Next Follow-up Date</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div flex class="pad-10 ">
        <strong><a href="" >Close</a></strong>
    </div> 
</div>
<md-list>
    <md-item data-ng-repeat="row in vm.vom | orderBy:prop:reverse | filter:search" class="moving finish" data-ng-class-odd="'stripeGrey'" data-ng-class-even="'stripeWhite'" data-ng-init="visible=''">
        <md-item-content ng-show="row.amount_due!= '$ 0.00'" layout="row" class="vom">

            <div flex>{{::row.open_date}}</div>
            <div flex>{{::row.invoice_no}}</div>
            <div flex><a href="/index.php/Collections/edit/?id={{::row.invcase_id}}">{{::row.invcase_id}}</a></div>
            <div flex>{{::row.amount_due}}</div>
            <div flex>{{::row.due_date}}</div>
            <div flex><a href="/index.php/Collections/cust_list/?id={{::row.obj_id}}">{{::row.customer}}</a></div>
            <div flex>{{::row.contact}}</div>
            <div flex>{{::row.followup_name}}</div>
            <div flex>
                {{::row.followup_date}}
                <span class="float-r point vanish formContainer">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-o" data-ng-mouseenter="visible=row[$index]"></i>
                    <div class="toolTip main-bg" data-ng-mouseleave="visible=''">
                        <md-content class="md-padding vanish" data-ng-repeat="option in row.notes" data-ng-show="visible==row[$index]">
                            <h5>{{option.date}}</h5>
                            <p>{{option.detail}}</p>
                        </md-content>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
              <div flex><md-button class="sm-raised sm-primary pad-10" href="" data-ng-click="vm.hideRow(row.invcase_id)">close</md-button></div> 

        </md-item-content>
        <md-divider data-ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
    </md-item>
</md-list>
```

So essentially I am trying to grab the value of that rows val.invoice_no and post it. Can someone explain what I could possibly change? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you refer to `rowId` and `rowID` which are two different variables in javascript.  Rename them to match.

You should also be waiting for your post to complete before attempting to refresh the page.  Do this by using a `.then()` function on your `$http.post`

Finally, I would suggest a couple of things to improve this code for best practices. What you have should work with the above modifications, and is fine if you're learning.  But once you get it working, I'd suggest refactoring the code as follows:

Setting window.location is a code smell.  I would rather see code here to re-download the data without refreshing the entire page.

It's best practice to put your $http code into a service, not the controller.

Comment: Wow, it is always the small things. I have adjusted my code above to reflect my changes. Thanks.